# Counting the occurence of record in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to count a lactation which means i am counting the dates calved of an animal: when calvDate for the animalid changes 1 is added to the lactationID to keep count. 
This are the five columns

```
#ID,LactationID,CalvDateLactationID, animalidLactationID,animalid, calvDate
'1', '1', '1 - 2018-08-08', '1 - T81', 'T81', '2018-08-08'
'2', '1', '1 - 2017-12-18', '1 - T66', 'T66', '2017-12-18'
'3', '2', '3 - 2017-12-28', '4 - T66', 'T66', '2017-12-28'
```

The query i am using to generate this output is

```
SELECT 
  dt.ID,
  @row_num := IF(@aid <> dt.animalid, 1, @row_num + 1) as LactationID,
  concat(@row_num := IF(@aid <> dt.animalid, 1, @row_num + 1),' - ',calvDate) AS CalvDateLactationID,
  concat(@row_num := IF(@aid <> dt.animalid, 1, @row_num + 1),' - ',animalid) AS animalidLactationID, 
  @aid := dt.animalid AS animalid,  dt.calvDate 
FROM 
(SELECT ID,animalid,calvDate FROM calvingdatecombined ORDER BY animalid, calvDate, ID) AS dt 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_num := 0, @aid := '') AS user_init_vars 
where calvDate <> '' and calvDate <> '0000-00-00' ORDER BY dt.ID
```

My expected output is

```
#ID, LactationID,CalvDateLactationID, animalidLactationID,animalid, calvDate

'1', '1', '1 - 2018-08-08', '1 - T81', 'T81', '2018-08-08'
'2', '1', '1 - 2017-12-18', '1 - T66', 'T66', '2017-12-18'
'3', '2', '2 - 2017-12-28', '2 - T66', 'T66', '2017-12-28'
```

what can i improve in my query to help me generate my expected output.

My calvingdatecombined table has the following columns and sample data

```
# ID, animalid, calvDate

'1', 'T81', '2018-08-08' 
'2', 'T66', '2017-12-18'
'3', 'T66', '2017-12-28'
```

Comment: You should show the data as it appears before the query.  Kind of hard to back that out using the expected output.

Comment: I have added the data content of calvingdatecombined @Tim BIegeleisen

Comment: Sometimes it's prudent to sacrifice reality for clarity.

Comment: @Strawberry Is that a reference to using LSD?  OMG...you use it too?!

Comment: @MirieriMogaka The added data isn't helping much.  A good SQL question would show a minimal table of sample data, then output, followed by a clear explanation of the logic involved.

Comment: @timbiegeleisen Hey, whatever gets you through the night

Comment: I am confused; your expected output is same as what your query is outputting! What exactly are you trying to do here ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya it is different look at lactationID - 189 instead of maintaining 2 all through it keeps counting

Comment: @MirieriMogaka with just your given sample data of only 7 rows, you really cannot reach row number (lactationID) value of 189. Please prepare and expected output based on your given sample data.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I have made the suggested changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer, just a suggestion, and too long for a comment:

A data set like this would lose none of the meaning, and would be considerably easier to read:

```
ID, animalid, calvDate
186, 81, '2018-08-08'
188, 66, '2017-12-18'
189, 66, '2017-12-28'
```

Comment: I have edited the question according to your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to increment `@row_num` value again for `CalvDateLactationID` and `animalidLactationID`.

Also, I have shifted the `Where` condition on `calvDate` to inner Select query, for further optimization. Use the following query instead:

```
SELECT 
  dt.ID,
  @row_num := IF(@aid <> dt.animalid, 1, @row_num + 1) as LactationID,
  concat(@row_num, ' - ', calvDate) AS CalvDateLactationID,
  concat(@row_num, ' - ', animalid) AS animalidLactationID, 
  @aid := dt.animalid AS animalid,  
  dt.calvDate 
FROM 
(
 SELECT ID,animalid,calvDate 
 FROM calvingdatecombined 
 WHERE calvDate > '0000-00-00' 
 ORDER BY animalid, calvDate, ID
) AS dt 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_num := 0, 
                   @aid := '') AS user_init_vars 
ORDER BY dt.ID
```

Comment: Incidentally, if you need a result set like this, I would seriously question your data model.